# Touch events in Codename One

Tags: codenameone

How can I capture select, drag & log press event on CodeName One?

```
protected void handleComponentAction(Component c, ActionEvent event)
```

This method is capturing **only** click event of button (Not capturing for Label) & not other.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Override pointerPressed/Released/Dragged or use the proper listeners in the form class.